# Why is the Emacs init file a hidden file?

Tags: emacs

Why is the Emacs initialization file -- .emacs, or .emacs.d/init.el -- a hidden file (or in a hidden directory)?  Is there some good reason for this?  It can make normal operations outside of Emacs unnecessarily awkward.

Dialog boxes in other programs don't deal well with hidden files.  For example, I tried to attach my .emacs.d/init.el to an email, in my Gmail account.  The Firefox/Gmail dialog doesn't show hidden files or folders, and doesn't let me type in the path name.

Comment: "doesn't let me type in the path name." -- That would be a failing of Firefox or Gmail, rather than this file naming convention.

Comment: You would be better off using a proper mail client instead of the Web.  Thunderbird shouldn't be too hard to use for an Emacs user!

Comment: Yes, attaching files would definitely be easier that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration files in your home directory are usually hidden in linux. Why shouldn't they be hidden? They're nothing you need to see all the time.

Comment: Hmmmm.  Probably true for most config files, but I tinker with my .emacs all time.

Comment: Then do `ln -s ~/.emacs ~/emacs`, so it'll always be visible in your home directory ;)

Comment: Dang, I should have thought of that!  Good idea!

Comment: Funny though, I most probably edit more of my home directory dotfiles than non-dotted ones. But yes, traditionally runconfig files are hidden from sight.

Answer (score 6):

It is so you can list your home directory without seeing the gazillion configuration files that are there.